# Using regex is there a magical way to add curly bracket between unknown amount of text?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm curious what is the shortest way to achieve this result in term of steps. Suppose I have a text:

```js
functionNameA(one)
functionNameB(one, two)
```

modify it becomes

```js
functionNameA({1one})
functionNameB({1one}, {2two})
```

As you can see we do not know the amount of text or word inside the bracket.
Is there a magical vb.net function to do this? Or do regex got this capability to perform this task?

Comment: Why not use Newtonsoft JSON, load it into a dynamic object, and then just reference what you need?

Comment: @RonBeyer well I guess that would work but right now I don't wish to install extra package since I don't work with json quite often. That said from the documentation I didn't see it provide function to skip to another scope like when "built_in" is met

Comment: Using magic is bad coding practice.

Comment: You could get the index of the first "(", the index of the last ")", get the substring between them, use `String.Join(", ", partBetweenParentheses.Split(","c).Select(Function(p) "{" & p.Trim() & "}"))`, and join the parts back together. But that doesn't use a regex.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I edited the question to increase the difficulty, what if inside the curly braket I want to add a number?

Comment: @alita `String.Join(", ", partBetweenParentheses.Split(","c).Select(Function(p, i) "{" & (i + 1) & p.Trim() & "}"))`

Comment: @AndrewMorton impressive on how short is this function, I ran on 2000 lines of text there is visible delay thought

Comment: @alita You would have to look carefully to find out where the delay is. For example, if the text was being written into a textbox, that could be slowing it down noticeably.